# Is there a way to color values in a dataframe if the belong to a certain range (Python-Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a data frame with values from 0 to 10. I would like to color the value 1 and 5 with red rather than black. Is that possible to do it in python DataFrame? I am using Jupyter notebook.

Comment: there is no way in the python side of notebook. what you can do is changing the javascript side of things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the `style` of cells -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'v1': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})
dft = df.style.applymap(lambda x: 'color: red' if x >= 1 and x <=5 else 'color: black')
dft
```

You can find more information about applying styles here - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html